# SvelteKit not seeing [id].svelte file

Tags: sveltekit

I am trying to access `/dashboard/tickets/test` root on my website, but always get 404. However, `/dashboard/tickets` works completely fine. Same thing applies to `[id].svelte`. I've tried a lot of different stuff and asked GPT about it, but no luck. Please help

Here is my folder structure

```
src
├── components
│   ├── TicketInList.svelte
│   └── TicketList.svelte
├── routes
│   └── dashboard
│       ├── tickets
|.      |.  |-- [id].svelte
│       │   ├── test.svelte
│       │   └── +page.svelte
│       ├── +page.svelte
│       └──+layout.svelte
```

My test file:

```html
<script context="module">
    import { goto } from '$app/navigation';
    
    function goBack() {
        goto('/dashboard/tickets');
    }
    </script>

    <h1>Test Route</h1>
    <button on:click={goBack}>Go back to tickets list</button>
```

Comment: sveltekit changed the way it does routing a few months ago. Now you should create a new folder for each route and put a `+page.svelte` there. For example, the new paths would be `/dashboard/tickets/test/+page.svelte` and `/dashboard/tickets/[id]/+page.svelte`. See https://www.netlify.com/blog/migrating-breaking-changes-in-sveltekit/ and https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing for more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Svelte has updated their routing way, so now `[id]` has to be a directory and inside of it it needs to have `+page.svelte`. This works now. [Related docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing).